How do I switch between a dash and automatic movement without creating an infinite loop?
I'm attempting to make a cube dash when the spacebar is pressed. I already have automatic movement in a random direction set up when the code starts executing. However I am uncertain how to switch between the two actions without creating an infinite loop.
I was thinking a of using a delegate but I am really not sure that would even look or be written. I also have the ability to rotate the cube and would like to be able to use that ability too.
private Vector3 RandomVector(float min, float max)
{
    var x = Random.Range(min, max);
    var y = Random.Range(min, max);
    return new Vector3(x, y);
}

void Dash()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, 0, 0);
}
 
 void Start()
 {
     Vector3 v = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Random.Range(360.0f, 0.0f), Vector3.forward) * 
     Vector3.up;

     GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = v * squareSpeed;

     if (Input.GetButtonDown("Dash"))
     {
         Dash();
     }
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
    {
        transform.Rotate(0.0f, 0.0f, 30f * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) 
    {
        transform.Rotate(-0.0f, 0.0f, -30f * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}


Some "commands" constitute multiple simpler commands; e.g. Halt; Dash; (Resume) RandomMovement; "chained" together. Using a "queue of commands", for example, attached to an object. Once you've scripted the "primitives", you can create more complex movements using them as building blocks.

Many problems in game development are solved by using state machines, it is probably a topic worth some study.
